# filtering in json keyed by id and returning an array; map without undefined

Tags: javascript, json, filter, key

I have

```
let list = { 
  1: { name: "someone1" },
  5: { name: "someone5" },
  7: { name: "someone7" },
  8: { name: "someone8" }
};
```

and I want to filter [1,5,42]

```
[
 { name: "someone1" },
 { name: "someone5" }
]
```

I tried

```
Object.keys(list).map(key=> {if([1,5,42].includes(key)) return list[key]});

[
 { name: "someone1" },
 { name: "someone5"},
 undefined, 
 undefined
]
```

---

PS: When my list was a json array, I used `list.filter(person => [1,5].includes(person.id))`. I then changed to keyed by id model, so I can use `liat[id]` which is way faster than list.filter for single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could directly iterate the filter array and take the object.

```js
let list = { 1: { name: "someone1" }, 5: { name: "someone5" }, 7: { name: "someone7" }, 8: { name: "someone8" } },
    filter = [1, 5],
    result = filter.map(k => list[k]);

console.log(result);
```

You need a different approach, if the filter contains strings, which are not keys of the object.

```js
let list = { 1: { name: "someone1" }, 5: { name: "someone5" }, 7: { name: "someone7" }, 8: { name: "someone8" } },
    filter = [1, 5, 42],
    result = filter.reduce((r, k) => r.concat(list[k] || []), []);

console.log(result);
```

A two step solution with mapping values of the object and filtering with `Boolean` for truthy elements.

```js
let list = { 1: { name: "someone1" }, 5: { name: "someone5" }, 7: { name: "someone7" }, 8: { name: "someone8" } },
    filter = [1, 5, 42],
    result = filter.map(key => list[key]).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Probably the simplest solution

Comment: I specifically wanted the 42 part..! made an edit in the question

Comment: So the trick is, since map always returns something, you used reduce and pushed to result array only if its not undefined...?

Comment: @NinaScholz now that we have an answer, efficiency?  :|

Comment: @ZekeDran, what do you mean by efficiency? which one? both have O(n).

Comment: eliminating `undefined` before pushing to array vs removing `undefined` after the array is built

Comment: worst case before: O(n), after o(2n), both linear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignment

```
let res = [];
({1:res[res.length], 5:res[res.length]} = list);
```

```js
let list = { 
  1: { name: "someone1" },
  5: { name: "someone5" },
  7: { name: "someone7" },
  8: { name: "someone8" }
};

let [keys, res] = [["1", "5"], []];

for (let key of keys) {({[key]:res[res.length]} = list)}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? `({1:res[res.length], 5:res[res.length]} = list);` and what happens when I have 42 in keys (a non existent key)?

Comment: @ZekeDran `{1:res[res.length]}` gets property `"1"` from object and assigns the value to `res[res.length]`. At first example the property keys are explicitly passed. At `for..of` loop the current array element is a computed property name within `[]`. The result of passing `42` or `"42"` would be an `undefined` element within resulting array. What is purpose of passing non-existent property within an array?

Comment: The list is fetched separately and the keys array is fetched separately from the server: keys come first! Since I'm using a redux store, list will be {} initially which makes the keys invalid at that time and not to mention that a couple of undefineds inside an array collapses the whole app

Comment: @ZekeDran You can include an `if` statement within `for..of` loop and use `in` operator or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`, `if (key in list) {({[key]:res[res.length]} = list)}` or `if (list.hasOwnProperty(key)) {({[key]:res[res.length]} = list)}`.

Answer (score 1):

**A one-liner solution**:

```
[1,5,42].map(key => list[key]).filter(el => el)
// if(el != null) return true shortened as el => el
```

Nina Scholz's simple one liner: `[1,5,42].reduce((r, k) => r.concat(list[k] || []), []);` is different in that it checks before adding it to the array while the above one removes `undefined`s after building the array.

**One more possible one-liner would be**:

```
["1","5","42"].filter(key => Object.keys(list).includes(key)).map(key => list[key])
//This one removes the invalid keys and then build an array without `undefined`s
```

**Snippet**:

```js
let list = { 
  1: { name: "someone1" },
  5: { name: "someone5" },
  7: { name: "someone7" },
  8: { name: "someone8" }
};

console.log([1,5,42].map(key => list[key]).filter(el => el));

console.log(["1","5","42"].filter(key => Object.keys(list).includes(key)).map(key => list[key]));
```

Comment: Requirement for "one-liner" does not appear at original Question. How is `javascript` at this Answer different from `javascript` at  @NinaScholz Answer? Have you benchmarked the time that `javascript` at each Answer takes to complete process? Not clear from original Question what the actual requirement is?

Comment: `One liner` is not the original requirement; **Your answer is actually an answer for my question and I can use it**; And these are just other possibilities I thought of....

Answer (score 0):

```js
let list = { 
  1: { name: "someone1" },
  5: { name: "someone5" },
  7: { name: "someone7" },
  8: { name: "someone8" }
};
function filter(ids, list){
  var ret = [];
  for(var i in ids){
    var id = ids[i];
    ret.push(list[id]);
  }
  return ret;
}
var filtered = filter([1,5], list);
console.log(filtered);
```

this solution assumes you only ask for existing keys.

Comment: thanks, but i made an edit to the question: I specifically need to eliminate `undefined`s if they are not present