# Delete id filter from objects and change it to simple format with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, loopbackjs

I have resultMp3 giving me this:

```
"mp3": {
  "33274": {
    "idSon": 33274,
    "description": "Techno Music",
    "Typenom": "Billboard",
  },
  "33275": {
    "idSon": 33275,
    "description": "Techno Music",
    "Typenom": "Pub Cd/Dvd",

  }
},
```

I want to delete simply the filter by id so result will be like this

```
"mp3": {
  {
    "idSon": 33274,
    "description": "Techno Music",
    "Typenom": "Billboard",
  },
  {
    "idSon": 33275,
    "description": "Techno Music",
    "Typenom": "Pub Cd/Dvd",
  }
},
```

This my function so far. Result is okay but my problem is that I want to delete the Id and still filter using it:

```
let resultMp3 = {};
let sqlPromise = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

  var ds = app.datasources.mydb;
  var sql = `....`;

  ds.connector.execute(sql, [], function (err, cm_comediens_extraits_mp3s) {

  if (cm_comediens_extraits_mp3s.length === 0){
    resultMp3 = {}
  }else{
    for(var i=0; i<cm_comediens_extraits_mp3s.length;i++){        
      let extraitMp3 = cm_comediens_extraits_mp3s[i];
      let mp3 = {};
      mp3["idSon"] = extraitMp3.idSon;
      mp3["description"] = extraitMp3.description;
      mp3["Typenom"] = valueList[extraitMp3.type].fr;

      resultMp3[extraitMp3.idSon] = mp3;   

    }
  }
   resolve(resultMp3);   

  }); 
});
result.mp3=resultMp3;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your desired output is impossible to do. An object need a key/value

Comment: so change it to an array of objects. is it possible ? check here :`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794393/filtering-in-json-keyed-by-id-and-returning-an-array-map-without-undefined`

Comment: Try [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values`

```js
let data = { "mp3": {
  "33274": {
    "idSon": 33274,
    "description": "Techno Music",
    "Typenom": "Billboard",
  },
  "33275": {
    "idSon": 33275,
    "description": "Techno Music",
    "Typenom": "Pub Cd/Dvd",

  }
}
};
let d = {"mp3" : Object.values(data.mp3)}
console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make an array of object, you can use `Object.values()`

```js
let obj = {
  "mp3": {
    "33274": {
      "idSon": 33274,
      "description": "Techno Music",
      "Typenom": "Billboard",
    },
    "33275": {
      "idSon": 33275,
      "description": "Techno Music",
      "Typenom": "Pub Cd/Dvd",

    }
  }
}

obj.mp3 = Object.values(obj.mp3)

console.log(obj)
```

---

In your case, you can initialise `resultMp3` as an array (`let resultMp3 = [];`) and replace this line

```
resultMp3[extraitMp3.idSon] = mp3;
```

By

```
resultMp3.push(mp3);
```