# What's the best way to add an indexed object to a Redux store (Redux Toolkit)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I've been storing everything in arrays up until now, but after coming across [this StachOverflow question about keyed object indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445006/state-as-array-of-objects-vs-object-keyed-by-id) and how traversing arrays can lead to a performance loss, I wanted to shift towards storing stuff as objects. I don't quite get the syntax however.

This reducer is meant to create an indexed object but it doesn't seem to work.  **How can I fix it to produce the desired object shape below?**

```js
type MsgPayload = {
  type: string;
  msgKey?: string;
  index?: number;
};

type IndexedMsgPayload = {
  [key: number]: MsgPayload;
};

const messengerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "messages",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    emitMessage: (state, action: PayloadAction<MsgPayload | any>) => {
      state.total++;
      const indexedObj: IndexedMsgPayload = {
        0: {
          ...action.payload,
        },
      };
      action.payload[state.total] = indexedObj[0];
      state.messages = { ...state.messages, ...action.payload[state.total] };
    },
  },
});
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```js
{
   1: { 
    type: 'type',
    msgKey: 'alert'
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux Toolkit already has a `createEntityAdapter` API that does the work of defining and updating a normalized state structure for you:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#normalizing-state
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization#normalizing-data